# why do we need weak entity instead of making it strong entity?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

For example, I have 2 entities: book and copy with 1-n relationship as a book can have many its copies.

if copy is a strong entity,

book(PK_ISBN#, title, edition, date) 
copy(PK_copy#, condition, FK_ISBN#)

if copy is a weak entity,

book(PK_ISBN#, title, edition, date) 
copy(ISBN#, copy#, condition) 
Primary key (ISBN#, copy#)
Foreign key ISBN# references book(PK_ISBN#)

**Question:** why would the copy entity be the weak entity instead of strong entity when both cases, I think, are similar.

P/S: one more question: How can we model partial or total participation constraint in SQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've probably realised, in practice there is little or no difference in SQL implementations between a table representing a strong entity and one representing a weak entity. The concept exists in ER notation but has very little relevance to the relational model or SQL except as a way of understanding the semantics of the domain of discourse.

Your examples are a little sketchy on details however. It appears that the copy attribute is unique in the first example but not in the second, which suggests the copy attribute means something different in each case.

A total participation constraint between two tables is usually impossible to enforce in SQL because Standard SQL doesn't support multiple assignment (you can't update both tables at once). The workaround is to disable or defer constraint checking during updates, which means such constraints are of only limited value. Partial participation is essentially what a foreign key constraint achieves.

Comment: so it means that weak entity does not have any advantage over the strong entity and they are similar, isn't it?

Comment: The question of whether some relationship is optional or not is potentially important but assuming the relationship is a mandatory one then *in context of the relational database model* there is no special advantage to either weak or strong. In terms of other (non relational) models there may perhaps be significant differences.

Comment: @nvogel "A total participation constraint between two tables is usually impossible to enforce in SQL" if i add `NOT NULL` together with `FOREIGN KEY` constraint i achieve a total participation

Answer (score 0):

Consider marriages. A marriage is a relationship between two persons.

Let's suppose `Person` is a strong entity set.
We can register `Marriage` as a relationship set that refers to the two participating persons.
It will then have two different foreign keys to `Person`: `Person`'s primary key will be included into `Marriage` twice (with different column names).

This will suffice, if all we need to record is whether two persons are married, or have been married.

We may add attributes, e.g. the date of marriage.

`Marriage` will continue to be a relationship set as long as the primary key consists of attributes in the foreign keys (i.e. marriages are identified by the identities of the marriage partners).

However, [Elizabeth Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Taylor) and [Richard Burton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Burton) were married twice.
If we need to be able to distinguish between those marriages, we'll need to record both separately, and we'll need to add an attribute to the primary key.

Let's say we add the date of marriage to the primary key (and hope no couple will ever marry twice on the same day).

Now, we have a weak entity: the primary key partly, but not completely, consists of foreign keys.

Is this a reasonable design?  It may be; if this is all the information we can gather about marriages, it may well be the best design.

However, chances are that we may be able to add other attributes that can help identify marriages.  For instance, if the purpose of our database is to serve as an official registry of marriages, chances are that the process of marriage involves stamping each marriage with an official code or number of some kind, that needs to be recorded, and hence, is a uniquely identifying attribute for marriages.

In that case, we can turn that attribute into the primary key, and voilà: `Marriage` is a strong entity.

In summary: whether something turns out to be a relationship, a weak entity, or a strong entity, depends not only on what you're trying to model, but also on what information about it you have available.